# Sass : Set $vars based upon @media

Tags: sass

- ***This is my first dabble into Sass mixins and includes.***

I wish to alter some columns widths based upon the current screen width, and my hope for a DRY approach was to set some global Sass variables based upon the matching (current) @media selection.

I seem to have wrongly assumed that the variables would be re-evaluated as the matching @media statement changed - eg device rotated. Nope.

I would like to end up with just one set of classes (outside of the @media sections) which use the appropriate value for the @media selection, **rather than** having to restate the classes within each individual @media section, e.g.

```
th.employee-name {
   width: $column_employee_name;
}
```

What I see is that the @mixin is called for all media widths, and the last time that it is called determines the final value of the variables.

**Question: Is there a way of achieving what I am trying to do - ie a DRY solution?**

```
@mixin column-definitions($app) {
    @if $app == "mobile" {
        $column_employee_name  : 130px !global;
        $column_business_role  : 135px !global;
        $column_company        : 020px !global;
        $column_company_heading: 'Tel' !global;
        $column_dept           : 075px !global;
        $column_extension      : 085px !global;
        $column_personal       : 150px !global;
        $column_nextofkin      : 150px !global;
        $table_width           : $column_business_role + $column_company + $column_employee_name !global;
    }
    @else {
        $column_employee_name  : 200px !global;
        $column_business_role  : 250px !global;
        $column_company        : 150px !global;
        $column_company_heading: 'S & B Mobile' !global;
        $column_dept           : 075px !global;
        $column_extension      : 085px !global;
        $column_personal       : 150px !global;
        $column_nextofkin      : 150px !global;
        $table_width           : $column_business_role + $column_company + $column_dept + $column_extension + $column_employee_name + $column_personal + $column_nextofkin + 20px !global;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    $app : mobile !global;
    @include column-definitions($app);
    // a.mobile-number { //     display: none; // }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:421px) {
    $app : pc !global;
    @include column-definitions($app);
    // a.mobile-icon { //     display: none; // }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to keep this DRY. In the following sample, the  and  classes which are variable widths according to the changing screen width, are listed once in the **@mixin column-definitions**

There are two **@media queries** which begin by setting the variables required by each variant, and then **@include column-definitions**

BTW - I have used global variables for the columns which do not alter their width responsively.

Simples!

```
$column_dept           : 075px !global;
$column_extension      : 085px !global;
$column_personal       : 150px !global;
$column_nextofkin      : 150px !global;

@mixin column-definitions($column_employee_name, $column_business_role, $column_company, $column_company_heading) {

    th.employee-name,
    td.employee-name {
        width    : $column_employee_name;
        max-width: $column_employee_name;
        min-width: $column_employee_name;
    }

    td.business-role,
    th.business-role {
        max-width: $column_business_role;
        min-width: $column_business_role;
    }

    td.company-mobile,
    th.company-mobile {
        max-width: $column_company;
        min-width: $column_company;
    }

    th.company-mobile::before {
        content: $column_company_heading;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {

    $column_employee_name  : 130px !global;
    $column_business_role  : 135px !global;
    $column_company        : 020px !global;
    $column_company_heading: 'Tel' !global;

    @include column-definitions($column_employee_name, $column_business_role, $column_company, $column_company_heading);

    $table_width           : $column_business_role + $column_company + $column_employee_name !global;

    a.mobile-number { display: none;  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:421px) {

    $column_employee_name  : 200px !global;
    $column_business_role  : 250px !global;
    $column_company        : 150px !global;
    $column_company_heading: 'S & B Mobile' !global;

    @include column-definitions($column_employee_name, $column_business_role, $column_company, $column_company_heading);

    $table_width           : $column_business_role + $column_company + $column_dept + $column_extension + $column_employee_name + $column_personal + $column_nextofkin + 20px !global;

    a.mobile-icon {   display: none; }
}
```